# Call a Python function from within a C program

Tags: python, c++, c, python-c-api

I have an application in C and at some point I need to solve a non-linear optimization problem. Unfortunately AFAIK there are very limited resources to do that in C (please let me know otherwise). However it is quite simple to do it in Python, e.g. [scipy.optimize.minimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html).

While I was trying to do that I encountered some of what it seems to be very frequent pitfalls, e.g. `Python.h` not found, module not loading, segmentation fault on function call, etc.

What is a quick and easy first-timer’s way to link the two programs?

Answer (score 11):

There are some things that you have to make sure are in place in order to make this work:

1. Make sure you have Python installed (you may need the `python-dev` package).
2. Locate your `Python.h` file, e.g. by `locate Python.h`. One of the occurrences should be in a sub(sub)folder in the `include` folder, e.g. the path should be something like `../include/python2.7/Python.h`.
3. Insert `#include “<path_to_Python.h>"` in your C code in order to be able to use the Python API.
4. Use any tutorial to call your Python function. I used [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11805/Embedding-Python-in-C-C-Part-I) and it did the trick. However there were a couple of small points missing:

   - Whenever you use any `Py<Name>` function, e.g. `PyImport_Import()`, **always** check the result to make sure there was no error, e.g.

     ```
     // Load the module object
     pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

     if (!pModule)
     {
         PyErr_Print();
         printf("ERROR in pModule\n");
         exit(1);
     }
     ```
   - Immediately after initializing the Python interpreter, i.e. after `Py_Initialize();`, you have to append the current path to `sys.path` in order to be able to load your module (assuming it is located in your current directory):

     ```
     PyObject *sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
     PyObject *path = PyObject_GetAttrString(sys, "path");
     PyList_Append(path, PyString_FromString("."));
     ```
5. Keep in mind that when you give the name of your Python file, it has to be **without** the extension `.py`.
6. Lastly, you have to do the following during compiling/linking:

   - Remember the `../include/python2.7/Python.h` file you used before? Include the `include` folder in the list of the header files directories with the `-I` option in the `gcc` options during compilation, e.g. `-I /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include`.
   - Also pass to the linker the folder with the required libraries. It should be inside the same folder where the `include` folder is located, e.g. `-L /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib`, along with the `-lpython2.7` option (of course adjusting it accordingly to your Python version).

Now you must be able to successfully compile and execute your C program that calls in it your Python program.

I hope this was helpful and good luck!

Sources:

- [How do you call Python code from C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056051/how-do-you-call-python-code-from-c-code)
- http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8497?page=0,1
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11805/Embedding-Python-in-C-C-Part-I
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11843/Embedding-Python-in-C-C-Part-II
- [Python C API doesn't load module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624529/python-c-api-doesnt-load-module)
- [What sets up sys.path with Python, and when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271494/what-sets-up-sys-path-with-python-and-when)
- http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc
- [PyObject segfault on function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207457/pyobject-segfault-on-function-call)
- [I have Python on my Ubuntu system, but gcc can't find Python.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282231/ubuntu-i-have-python-but-gcc-cant-find-python-h)
- [How do you call Python code from C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056051/how-do-you-call-python-code-from-c-code)