# Extending Python in C

Tags: c++

I have successfully extended my python code in C following this:

[Call a Python function from within a C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316485/call-a-python-function-from-within-a-c-program)

I have compiled the code and created a .dll. However, when I opened it with the [dependencywalker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) I have seen that it still requires the python code. I want the dll to be standalone, so it doesn't depend on the script .py. I thought that using the tag `-static` in g++ would be enough but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: You want a Python subroutine in your C-program, or you want a C-subroutine in your Python program?

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond I want the Python subroutine in my compiled C-Program, so I don't need to have the python source code in the same folder.

Comment: Then find a Python-to-C or Python-to-machine_code translator.

Answer (score 2):

The Python documentation has a chapter on [Extending and Embedding Python with C](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html).

With good enough coding conventions this can by applied to C++ code. You will use `extern "C"` to declare functions coded in C++ callable from C.

Be careful to avoid [`throw`ing a C++ exception](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/exceptions) to Python code.

On Linux, see also [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [dlsym(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) and the [C++ dlopen mini howto](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/index.html).

Python is open source. You should consider downloading [its C source code](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/) and studying it.

Be aware of the [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock) in Python. Multi-threading C++ code will be tricky.

Consider also *generating* C or C++ code with tools like [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) or [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/), or writing in Python your C or C++ code generator.

Perhaps use static source code analyzers (like [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) or [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/)) on your C source code.

**Be aware that C and C++ are *different* programming languages**. See [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) and [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) and [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) or better.